# Genetic algorithms in python, having trouble with cumulative returns

Tags: python, data-analysis, genetic-algorithm

[Cumulative return graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eG5E.png) as you can see in the image when i graphic the cumulative returns of the different portfolios over a year, the only one that starts over 1 is the "Overall", but the rest of portfolios start in 0.

````
```
#Calculate the cumulative returns of the overall portfolio for 2017, 2018 and 2019

daily_portfolio_returns_2017 = (log_returns * best_ind).sum(axis=1)
cumulative_returns_2017 = (1 + daily_portfolio_returns_2017).cumprod()

daily_portfolio_returns_2018 = (log_returns_2018 * best_ind).sum(axis=1)
cumulative_returns_2018 = (1 + daily_portfolio_returns_2018).cumprod()

daily_portfolio_returns_2019 = (log_returns_2019 * best_ind).sum(axis=1)
cumulative_returns_2019 = (1 + daily_portfolio_returns_2019).cumprod()
```
```
# Calculate the daily returns for the risk taker and balanced portfolios for each year
risk_taker_returns_2017 = (log_returns * best_ind_risk_taker).sum(axis=1)
risk_taker_returns_2018 = (log_returns_2018 * best_ind_risk_taker).sum(axis=1)
risk_taker_returns_2019 = (log_returns_2019 * best_ind_risk_taker).sum(axis=1)

balanced_returns_2017 = (log_returns * best_ind_balanced).sum(axis=1)
balanced_returns_2018 = (log_returns_2018 * best_ind_balanced).sum(axis=1)
balanced_returns_2019 = (log_returns_2019 * best_ind_balanced).sum(axis=1)

risk_averse_returns_2017 = (log_returns * best_ind_risk_averse).sum(axis=1)
risk_averse_returns_2018 = (log_returns_2018 * best_ind_risk_averse).sum(axis=1)
risk_averse_returns_2019 = (log_returns_2019 * best_ind_risk_averse).sum(axis=1)

# Calculate the cumulative returns for the risk taker, risk averse and balanced portfolios for each year
cumulative_returns_risk_taker = {
    '2017': (1 + risk_taker_returns_2017).cumprod(),
    '2018': (1 + risk_taker_returns_2018).cumprod(),
    '2019': (1 + risk_taker_returns_2019).cumprod()
}

cumulative_returns_risk_averse = {
    '2017': (1 + risk_averse_returns_2017).cumprod(),
    '2018': (1 + risk_averse_returns_2018).cumprod(),
    '2019': (1 + risk_averse_returns_2019).cumprod()
}

cumulative_returns_balanced = {
    '2017': (1 + balanced_returns_2017).cumprod(),
    '2018': (1 + balanced_returns_2018).cumprod(),
    '2019': (1 + balanced_returns_2019).cumprod()
}

```
````

https://github.com/MaximoFigueroa457/Repo-Data-Science.git

I dont know if this results are correct, if i need to change some calculation, please helppp
Also any corrections within my code will be welcomed

Comment: Please add the code you're having trouble with to the question - not hyperlinks

Comment: Thank you, is my first time using stackoverflow to get help

Comment: If you don't know if the results are correct or what is wrong with the results you are getting, this is not the correct site to get the answer, since we don't provide tutoring service or debugging services.